# How do you delay the return statement of a function?

Tags: java, android

I have a piece of code where a function opens a popup window to later return an integer based on what happened inside that window. But when I run it, it directly returns the integer without opening any popup window.

**How do I tell that function to wait to return until a user has done a certain action?**

Here's the code in case you need it:

```
public int initPopup(String monsterName, String monsterHP){
    final int monsterHPInt = Integer.parseInt(monsterHP);
    PopupWindow popup;
    TextView popupText;
    Button closePopupButton;
    final SeekBar monsterHPChanger;
    LinearLayout popupLayout;

    popupText = new TextView(this);
    popupText.setText(monsterName);

    monsterHPChanger = new SeekBar(this);
    monsterHPChanger.setMax(monsterHPInt);
    /** Will only use if necessary
     *  monsterHPChanger.setProgress(monsterHPChanger.getMax());
     */

    popupLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    popupLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    popupLayout.addView(popupText);
    popupLayout.addView(monsterHPChanger);
    //TODO: Create the layout of the popup and the popup itself
    popup = new PopupWindow(popupLayout, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setContentView(popupLayout);

    //Creating encapsulation class to edit the monsterHP with the value of the SeekBar
    final MonsterHP monsterHPObject = new MonsterHP(monsterHPInt, monsterHPChanger.getProgress());
    closePopupButton = new Button(this);
    closePopupButton.setId(R.id.closePopup);
    closePopupButton.setText("Ok");

    closePopupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            monsterHPObject.update(monsterHPChanger.getProgress());
        }
    });

    Log.println(1, "Method", "Returns " + monsterHPObject.getHP());
    // TODO: reactivate when debug is done return monsterHPObject.getHP();
    //Returning 0 for debug reasons
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: while ( !userPerformedAction ){giveUserChanceToPerformAction();}
return result; Personally, I don't see any reason why this init should have a return statement. It's not the int of this return statement you want to have returned anyway.

Comment: Side note on code quality: your method is doing **way to many** different things. You should break it up in many smaller methods; otherwise it will become very hard to maintain ... very soon. Well; I find it unmaintable by now ... in other words: alone the idea that your method is doing all things in a single place is not good.You better build one or more classes to take care of the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! And yes, this is my very first App, I'm aware it's as horrible as it gets. I'm sorry if I have caused any eyesight loss or traumatized those who are not used to such aberrations.

Comment: @Stultuske It has a return statement because somewhere else I do something like this: `  textMonsterMaxHP.setText(initPopup(monsterName, monsterMaxHP)+"");`

Comment: @Lorenz: that wasn't the point. the point was to show how to delay the execution of the return statement

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for the tip, but I already tried while (popup.isShown()) {button that closes the popup} return result; and the App just freezes for the following `Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.`

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking your code and I dont see the call "popup.show()" anywhere. Also, if you want to wait some time to perform an operation you can use the following code.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // your operations (open popup?)
                }
}, **your_delay_time**);
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: I did forget show() but the problem still persists. It is not after a certain time that I want an action performed, it's once a user performs a certain action or the state of something changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback interface that you pass to your method. 
When the user performs the action, call the appropriate callback method.